# How Do You Exclude Jekyll's _site directory from VS Code to Prevent Compiler Warnings

Tags: typescript, jekyll, visual-studio-code

I'm using Jekyll, Typescript and VSCode together.

I have _site in my exclude files settings both for files and watcher:

[[image: Settings]]

And this is confirmed to be correct, as it has disappeared from the explorer.

However, when I go to my typescript file, I get these warnings all over the place:

[[image: Compiler warnings]]

This is because visual studio is detecting the `.ts` file that Jekyll has duplicated behind the scenes. How do I go about eliminating this compiler warning?